# Oracle Access manager Integration with Grails

Tags: grails, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I had Created Grails Application, I want OAM SSO to be implemented.

Earlier I was using Ntlm plugin, which was working in IE8 but not in IE9.

In internet explorer 9, I was having problem like many time it ask for Login Pop up, I have around 10000 customers so I cannot tell to any one to change settings.

So I want to implement Oracle Access manager, which should access Network login and authenticate, which when I use Ntlm works but as ntlm doesnt works on Internet explorer 9, so I want OAM to be configured with grails..

So Final I want OAM SSO integration (windows integrated network login based) which can authenticate.

I want only one time SSO pop up in IE.

I want finally OAM SSO integration with grails which will directly talk with microsoft active directory integrated with OAM.

So usecase will be like:

1. I open Login page it should through me popup for login
2. I will enter my network Credential which is used to login to windows PC using network Login.
3. Once it authenticates , takes to main page.
4. next time when i click to other pages in same application it should not ask for Login again.

Comment: It seems that Oracle have a [Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/apirefs.1111/e22472/toc.htm) to OAM.

Comment: @Sérgio Michels can you please tell me how to use those API or can you give me overview , what setup i requires, like according to you:-

1. I must setup oracle 11g, and i must connect with Active directory configuration.

2. Next step will be like that using That API which u had shared , i must authenticate user correct.


Can you please tell me more on this

Comment: I never used it, you will need to do some research.

Comment: Can you please help me for the right way, i will do and try rest.

Now i had installed everything , i just need to integrate OAM with my grails application

Comment: @sergio-michels

Can you tell me if i want to integrate OAM with java application how to do that...

Comment: As I said before, I never used it. But have you searched about this on Google? I just typed "OAM java example", it shows a lot of results... Here's a example: http://blog.sbeynon.net/2012/01/fun-with-oam-11g-sdk.html